# Problema na execução das Threads , usando flags

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Estou com uns problemas no entendimento completo do código pois sou novo na utilização do java em thread. O que código vai fazer é controlar o fluxo, fazendo 55 iterações dividindo entre a thread e programa principal (main):

```
Resultado:
Main Thread.: 1
New Thread..: 2
Main Thread.: 3
New Thread..: 4
...
Main Thread.: 51
New Thread..: 52
Main Thread.: 53
New Thread..: 54
```

Até aí tudo bem , o problema está , quando em certa execução o programa entra em alguns loop infinito e não para de executar outra vezes ele completa a execução , queria ajuda para entender este problema.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 /
package testando;

/*
 *
 * @author Márcio
 */
public class Testando {
static int value = 0;
static int flag = 1;

@SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                class MyThread extends Thread {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                while(flag == 1);
                                while(++value < 55) {
                                        System.out.println("New Thread..: " + value);
                                        flag = 1;
                                        while( value < 55 && flag == 1);
                                }
                        }
                }

                Thread thread1 = new MyThread();
                thread1.start();
                System.out.println(flag == 0);
                while(flag == 0);
                while(++value < 55) {
                        System.out.println("Main Thread.: " + value);
                        flag = 0;
                        while( value < 55 && flag == 0);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(flag == 1);` pra que isso?

Comment: Meu estava testando aqui, vir o código executar sem está função,  e sem também `while(flag == 0);` , peço que desconsidere esta parte.

Comment: Poderia remover as tags desnecessárias dentro da sua pergunta e do código?

Answer (score 4):

O que está causando *racing conditions* no seu código é o fato do acesso às variáveis não ser atômica, isto é, elas são acessadas concorrentemente por mais de um *thread*. Se você quer que essas variáveis sejam usadas pelo código sem que a operação executada em um *thread* afete a operação executada pelo outro, você deve encapsular as operações de leitura e alteração do valor das variáveis em blocos `synchronized` (dentro dos quais somente pode entrar um *thread* de cada vez) ou então usar objetos que garantam a atomicidade da operação como por exemplo [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: O problema é esse mesmo, mas acho que `AtomicInteger` não vai adiantar nesse caso porque o incremento e o teste da variável acontecem em locais separados.

Comment: É verdade. Mas as operações de incremento e teste não precisam ser dentro do mesmo bloco `synchronized`, apenas cada uma delas deve ser atômica, não? A API de `AtomicInteger` talvez resolva isso, com métodos como por exemplo `compareAndSet()`. Ou essa mesma API pode permitir que o par de ações em si seja atômico.

Comment: Não havia analisado o código com calma. Se for reescrito de maneira adequada o `AtomicInteger` provavelmente resolve. O problema é que o código está meio gambiarrado, esses *loops* "infinitos" ali para fazer sincronização não me cheiram bem.

Comment: Ah, sim. Provavelmente o OP necessita de uma solução com `wait()` e `notify()/notifyAll()` para permitir que os _threads_ se alternem no incremento da variável, dispensando uma `flag` de controle.

Comment: Um [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), um [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) ou uma [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) com duas [Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) também podem ser usados para evitar a espera ocupada e a flag.